# URL for a Drupal Web File Manager file by path and name

Tags: uri

Once a file is uploaded using the Drupal [Web File Manager](https://drupal.org/project/webfm), it can be referenced using a URL which has a number for identifying the file, like:

> https://intranet.example.com/drupal/webfm_send/**389**

Given that there is a path and name associated with the file such as:

> IT/Documentation/Projects/SomeProject/AFile.pdf

is there a URL that uses this path and name? Something like:

> https://intranet.example.com/drupal/*BYNAME*/**Documentation/Projects/SomeProject/AFile.pdf**

If so what is the *BYNAME* part of the URL?